# UpdateMany Not a Function MongoDB + Node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, monk

I am writing a piece of code to be run on an npm-cron timer. Here it is:

```
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
var job = new CronJob({
  cronTime: '* * * * *',
  onTick: function() {
    var monk = require('monk'); // persistence module over MongoDB
    var db = monk('localhost:27017/test');

    console.log("Hello from the Cron job! " + new Date());
    var collection = db.get('Activity');

    collection.updateMany({"repetitions.today": {$gt: 0}},
    {
        $set: {
            "repetitions.today": 0,
        }
    }, function(err, activity){
        if (err) throw err;
    });


  },
  start: true,
  timeZone: 'America/Los_Angeles'
});
job.start();
```

The problem is that I get an error on the `collection.updateMany()` line. The error states that

> updateMany is not a function

On the other hand, if i use `update()` instead of `updateMany()`, the code works (but only on the first item in Mongo collection, as expected). What am I doing wrong and what could be causing this?

I tried re-writing this using `foreach()` but it is also not recognized as a function.

Comment: Did you try using {multi: true} as an option for the update query?
collection.update({"repetitions.today": {$gt: 0}},
    {
        $set: {
            "repetitions.today": 0,
        }
    }, 
    { multi: true }

Comment: That worked! Do you know if it is the same as updateMany()? I am still curious why I was experiencing the problem described above.

Comment: Not sure, updateMany() requires version 3.2 or newer of MongoDB.  Which version are you using?  (mongo --version)

Comment: MongoDB shell version: 3.2.4

Comment: quick look at the docs for monk, and i don't see updateMany in their api. I've always used `update` with `multi: true` - although i use an older version of mongo (2.6)

Comment: That explains it then ...

Comment: you could maybe use bulkWrite if it fits your usecase - https://automattic.github.io/monk/docs/collection/bulkWrite.html

Answer (score 2):

Hmm....

Might want to try something like this (ES6)

```
db.collection('Activity').updateMany({"repetitions.today": {$gt: 0}},
{
    $set: { "repetitions.today": 0 }
}).then(r => {
    console.log('Success!');
}).catch(err => {
    console.log('Error - ' + err);
});
```